# Modify a line and append if needed

Tags: ansible

Using Ansible i want to modify an existing configuration file and change a specific setting (variable) depending on one or more vars that i specify in a customer specific playbook.

The configuration file contains:

```
JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS=""
```

The following option should always be added;

```
-Datlassian.plugins.enable.wait=300
```

Thus resulting in:

```
JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS="-Datlassian.plugins.enable.wait=300"
```

However, I have also some optional options to set, like when proxy settings are required;

```
-Datlassian.plugins.enable.wait=300 -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.xxx.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.xxx.com -Dhttps.proxyPort=3128 -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts='localhost'"
```

Or when we need to disable some sort of SSL Endpoint Identification:

```
JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS="-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification=true"
```

Some customers do not require the proxy or endpoint setting, some require both and some only one of these.

I tried to provide 'as-is' lines so it will just replace the entire thing, but this is not neat and is not desired either as there can be multiple combinations and I don't want to program all of them on beforehand. I rather have the variable build by adding the options I need.

```
  lineinfile:
    name: "{{ file.stat.path }}"
    regexp: '^JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS="'
    line: "JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS=\"-Datlassian.plugins.enable.wait=300\""
  when: file.stat.exists

- name: Ensure JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS proxy settings are present
  lineinfile:
    name: "{{ file.stat.path }}"
    regexp: '^JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS="'
    line: "JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS=\"-Datlassian.plugins.enable.wait=300
           -Dhttp.proxyHost={{ jira_http_proxy }} -Dhttp.proxyPort={{ jira_http_proxyport }} -Dhttps.proxyHost={{ jira_https_proxy }}
           -Dhttps.proxyPort={{ jira_https_proxyport }} -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts='{{ jira_non_proxy_hosts|default([])|join('|') }}'\""
  when: file.stat.exists and (jira_http_proxy|default(false) or jira_https_proxy|default(false))
```

**edit**

I can do it like this;

```
jira_base_args: "-Datlassian.plugins.enable.wait=300"
jira_proxy_args: "-Dhttp.proxyHost={{ jira_http_proxy }} -Dhttp.proxyPort={{ jira_http_proxyport }}
                  -Dhttps.proxyHost={{ jira_https_proxy }} -Dhttps.proxyPort={{ jira_https_proxyport }}
                  -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts='{{ jira_non_proxy_hosts|default([])|join('|') }}'"
jira_ldap_args: "-Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.object.disableEndpointIdentification=true"
```

And in the Playbook role;

```
  replace:
    name: "{{ file.stat.path }}"
    regexp: '^JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS=(.*)'
    replace: "JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS=\"{{ jira_base_args }}\""
  when: file.stat.exists

- name: Ensure JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS proxy settings are present
  replace:
    name: "{{ file.stat.path }}"
    regexp: '^JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS=(.*)'
    replace: "JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS=\"{{ jira_base_args }} {{ jira_proxy_args }}\""
  when: file.stat.exists and (jira_http_proxy|default(false) or jira_https_proxy|default(false))

- name: Ensure JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS ldap settings are present
  replace:
    name: "{{ file.stat.path }}"
    regexp: '^JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS=(.*)'
    replace: "JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS=\"{{ jira_base_args }} {{ jira_ldap_args }}\""
  when: file.stat.exists and (jira_disable_endpoint_ident|default(false))
```

But how to handle situations where both proxy and ldap settings are needed? Because the latter is now overwriting the proxy ones.

**edit**

Fixed it like this, not very nice but who has something better?

```
# We know that the default plugin timeout for JIRA is too low in most cases.
- name: Set plugin timeout to 300s
  replace:
    name: "{{ file.stat.path }}"
    regexp: '^JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS=(.*)'
    replace: "JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS=\"{{ jira_base_args }}\""
  when:
    - file.stat.exists
    - not jira_http_proxy|default(false)
    - not jira_https_proxy|default(false)
    - not jira_disable_endpoint_ident|default(false)

- name: Ensure JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS proxy settings are present
  replace:
    name: "{{ file.stat.path }}"
    regexp: '^JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS=(.*)'
    replace: "JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS=\"{{ jira_base_args }} {{ jira_proxy_args }}\""
  when:
    - file.stat.exists
    - jira_http_proxy|default(false)
    - jira_https_proxy|default(false)
    - not jira_disable_endpoint_ident|default(false)

- name: Ensure JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS ldap settings are present
  replace:
    name: "{{ file.stat.path }}"
    regexp: '^JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS=(.*)'
    replace: "JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS=\"{{ jira_base_args }} {{ jira_ldap_args }}\""
  when:
    - file.stat.exists
    - not jira_http_proxy|default(false)
    - not jira_https_proxy|default(false)
    - jira_disable_endpoint_ident|default(false)

- name: Ensure JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS proxy + ldap settings are present
  replace:
    name: "{{ file.stat.path }}"
    regexp: '^JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS=(.*)'
    replace: "JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS=\"{{ jira_base_args }} {{ jira_proxy_args }} {{ jira_ldap_args }}\""
  when:
    - file.stat.exists
    - jira_http_proxy|default(false)
    - jira_https_proxy|default(false)
    - jira_disable_endpoint_ident|default(false)
```

Comment: Just an idea: use tasks to set facts with each of the *segments* you want to add to the full variable, e.g. 
JIRA_BASE_ARGS="-Datlassian.plugins.enable.wait=300". And the collate all of the facts in the `lineinfile` task. You might need  *dummy* tasks to set the fact to an empty string if that part does not apply. Haven't tried this before, so I don't have an example to share.

Comment: See my edit please :)

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage `insertbefore` and `backrefs:yes` in [`lineinfile`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/lineinfile_module.html) module.

Example:

```
    - name: Set Atlassian enable.wait to 300s
      lineinfile:
        path: file.txt
        regexp: '^(JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS=".*)"$'
        insertbefore: '"$'
        line: '\1 -Datlassian.plugins.enable.wait=300"'
        state: present
        backrefs: yes
```

Comment: Thanks :) However, when running multiple times, it keeps adding the line as follows; ```JVM_SUPPORT_RECOMMENDED_ARGS="-Datlassian.plugins.enable.wait=300-Datlassian.plugins.enable.wait=300"```